# svn --summarize ignores moved files

Tags: svn, diff

```
svn mv dir1/a.cpp dir2/a.cpp

svn diff | grep ^Index
Index: dir1/a.cpp

svn diff --show-copies-as-adds | grep ^Index
Index: dir1/a.cpp
Index: dir2/a.cpp

svn diff --summarize
D       dir1/a.cpp

svn diff --show-copies-as-adds --summarize
D       dir1/a.cpp
```

I want to list the currently modified files. `svn diff --summarize` mostly works fine except for files that were moved. `svn diff` returns just the deleted files (files that were moved **from**). Option `--show-copies-as-adds` helps here as you can see above. However, the `--summarize` flag seems to ignore `--show-copies-as-adds`. What I need is something like this:

```
svn diff --show-copies-as-adds --summarize-better
D       dir1/a.cpp
A       dir2/a.cpp
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe `svn status`?

Comment: Yes, eventually I used `svn status -q` with some additional work. But I'm not sure if that's the best way though.